# How to update SQL Server database every 1 minute?

Tags: asp.net, sql, sql-server, asp.net-mvc

I have a SQL Server database which contains stock market quotes and other related data.

This database needs to be updated at regular interval, say 1 minute.

My question is:

> How do I get stock quotes every 1 minute and update it to database?

I really appreciate your help.

Thanks!

Comment: i think you'll probably need to narrow the scope of this one a little bit.  i see you've tagged the question with asp.net and mvc, but surely you won't won't actually want to do this using asp.net.  seems much better suited to something like a service.  also, do you have a service selected that will provide you with stock quotes?

Comment: Really? "Not a real question": This question is ambiguous, vague, incomplete, overly broad, or rhetorical and cannot be reasonably answered in its current form. That's pretty much the opposite of this question - if anything I'd say too localized, but it's pretty obvious what he's looking for here.

Comment: Hi Marek, I would like to go for an SQL Server job.

Comment: won't work. No job works - this cries for a windows process connected to a data feed ;) See my answer.

Comment: Ok. So if I have to connect this database to a website (which display values from database), how does Windows process fit into this? Can you please elaborate? Thanks
!

Comment: Well, you talk of some process that has to runn all the time to collect data, possibly getting it from a feed with a native API. The website basically has to pull sql, and the data moves into sql a different path. Not every problem is so simple that "make a website" is the technologically good answer. Exchange, sql server etc. all are not websites for some good reasons. This problem here asks for a pricing engine to run 24/7, which is something a web service can do better than a website.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You know, you seriously put the question from the wrong side. Like "I have a car, Mercedes, Coupe - how can I find the best road from A to B". Totally unrelated to the car.

Same with your question - this is not a sql or even an asp.net question to start with. The solution is independant of both, the sql server used and your web technology. Your main question is:

> How do I get stock quotes every 12 minute and update it to the database?

Here we go. I assume you (a) talk of US stocks and (b) mean all of them, not a handfull.. 1 minute is too small an interval to make scanning things like yahoo.com feasible - main problem here is that there are tousands of stocks (actually more in the tens of thousands), and you dont want to go to yahoo scrapping thousands of pages per minute.

Same time, a end retail user data feed provider will not work. They support X symbols at a time, and x being typcially in the low hundred area, sometimes upgradable to 500 or so.

If you need STOCK DATA every minute, as per all US stocks, then this is technically identical to "real time prices", which ends up costing money. In adition you need a commercial higher end data feed of which I know of... one. Sorry. Costs going to be near or full four digit, without (!) publication rights.

And that is NxCore - their system has a data offer that offers US Stocks (all exchanges) real time, complete feed with all corretions etc. Native and C# wrapper API, so you can take the real time data feed, update your current pricing in memory and write them out to sql server every minute. Preferably not from asp.net (baaaaad choice for something that should run 24/7 without interruption unless you do heavy setup changes etc.) but from an installed windows service. Takes some bandwidth - no real idea how much (I am getting 4 exchanges from them, but no stocks, only the cme group futures, CME, CBOT, NYMEX and COMEX).

Note that wwith this setup you can go faster, too, but if you go fully real time you need a serious server. We talk of a billion updates or so per day...
 End user sql server setup (i.e. little ram, and few slow discs) wont work.
Too expensive? Ther are plenty of data feeds around for a lower price, but they will not give you "stocks" as in "all of them", just "a selection".

If you are ok with not real time data - i.e. pulling stuff down at the end of the day, eoddata.com has a decent offer. YOu could also thnen pull things up via an asp.net page, but again.... you will not have the data during the day, just - well - after close. Smallest granularity is 1 minute. Repluublication rights again a no - but probably you can talk to them.

Comment: I am only interested in getting quotes from Top 10 Global indices like S&P500, Dow, FTSE, DAX, CAC, etc. Is there a provider which offers this real time or delayed?

Comment: Not that i Know of. And it is not really good for long term archival as those change. I simply am no in this area - I decided to get NxCore so I can actually start archiving every tick on the excahgnes that interest me for later review and analysis in maybe some years. Top list providers... really no idea.

Answer (score 1):

This isn't really SQL Server specific; a typical solution is that your run a process that polls an external source (a web service or the like) at regular intervals and uses this information to update the database. You can either implement this as a simple command-line program that gets executed every minute from the task scheduler, or you can make it a windows service that sleeps most of the time and only wakes up once a minute to do its processing. Once you have that, writing to the database is as usual.

Comment: As per original question - noone would use a web service for that. Sorry. Main reason is that we talk of a LOT of updates, even if pulled once per minute. Pretty much requires a more dense format than XML. Heck, FIX gor burned using clear text (one quote per line) for being too verbose, so they moved to binary fast (called FIX). XML is a nightmare here. Depending what "quotes" mean we possibly talk of 300.000 items here. Conservatively (due to stocks trading on multiple exchanges).

Comment: I never said XML. "Web service" simply means a HTTP resource that dynamically serves data. XML is a common choice, but I agree with you that for speed-critical application, a more efficient format is a much better choice - simple text-based, CSV, or if more structure is required, JSON or YAML.